# Curated data: Human cone responses?

Tags: color, curated-data

Does *Mathematica* have curated data on the spectral responses of the three classes of [human cones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_vision#/media/File:Cone-fundamentals-with-srgb-spectrum.svg) (for color vision)?